# Cocking the gun tactical motif (preparing a discovered attack)

Tags: tactics, terminology

There is a tactical motif I call "cocking the gun" which I have never seen explicitly mentioned. It happens when you prepare a discovered attack. See the following board. Is there an official name for this tactical motif?

From a [Lichess puzzle](https://lichess.org/training/77771)

```
[Event "Cocking the gun"]
[Date "2020.07.25"]
[Round "-"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "5rk1/1p1q3p/p2pp1p1/2p5/4P1QP/2PP2b1/PP2Br2/2KR3R b - - 0 1"]

1... Rg2 2.Rdf1 Bf4+ 3.Rxf4 Rxg4
```

Comment: There's a name for that: it's called "discovered attack"

Comment: @David not quite. Discovered attack is the next move, In this case you are setting up a discovered attack.

Comment: Setting up a tactical threat is not called anything in and of itself

Comment: @Roland that's the point. You are setting a discovered attack. We don't assign a specific name for the preparation of each tactical motif. That'd be pretty inefficient

Answer (score 1):

In Dutch, the two attacking pieces involved in a discovered attack (or the two defending ones in a pin, which is basically the flip side of a discovered attack) are called 'kopstuk' and 'staartstuk', literally translated 'head piece' (the black bishop) and 'tail piece' (the black rook). Preparing a discovered attack like this is called 'staartstuk plaatsen', literally translated 'putting the tail piece in place'. I *think* it has been coined in the [official Dutch method for teaching chess](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stappenmethode) which has been used widely since the 1990's, so many younger and middle-aged players here know the term.

I'm not sure if there's even a well-established (let alone official) English terminology for the 'tail piece'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovered_attack) doesn't mention it. Perhaps 'hidden piece' makes sense? Then you'd be 'putting the hidden piece in place', but as you can see, this is far from being official. I like your own phrase better.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **battery**.

Hooper & Whyld's *The Oxford Companion to Chess* says "**battery**" is "a problem term for one of the two kinds of ambush: a line-piece would command a line if another man of the same colour were moved off that line. Discovered checks arise from this kind of ambush. ... Players occasionally use the word '[battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(chess))' to describe doubled or tripled line-pieces; [problem] composers rarely use the word in this sense."

That book says that **ambush** is a term for a situation where a line-piece would command a line if another man [of no matter which colour] were moved off that line.

Sometimes these terms are used: **rear piece** for the piece whose attack line gets opened/discovered, and **front piece/unit** for the one that moves to open this line.

Problemists don't need the word **battery** to cover situations where the two pieces defend each other: they have other terms such as [Turton doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turton_doubling) and [Zepler doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zepler_doubling), depending on how the pieces move once they are on the same line.